# When to use camlQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom, c-sharp

When interacting with Sharepoint 2013 or Sharepoint Online, is the use of camlQuery recommended? I've had to pick up some CSOM knowledge of late on the fly via C#. I am having some success with it, and using Linq to get at what I need. For example: List.RootFolder, GetListByName, RootFolder.FindFiles, etc.

Are there actions you *must* use camlQuery for? Is everything you need accessible via the object model? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caml query helpful when you need filter(complex filter logic) data. [Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)

You could use rest api to get data also.

[pnp library](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/README.md) become popular, it'll help you code less.

Also check below official guideline to choose right solution.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint